# How can I change the targeted framework from 4.0 to 4.0.3

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, portable-class-library

I have the Portable Library Tools beta 2 installed in Visual Studio 2010.  I created a new library and set it to be compatible with .Net 4.0.3 and Silverlight 5.  I then tried to add a reference to the PCL project from a Silverlight Web project.  I got the message:

> Unable to add a reference to project "PortableClassLibrary". The
>   current project's target framework is not one of or compatible with
>   the target frameworks of Portable Library project
>   "PortableClassLibrary".
>
> A Portable Library project's target frameworks can be changed via the
>   Library tab in the project's properties.

I don't want to change the PCL target, I want to change the target of the Web project.  I went the the Properties > Application tab and the Target framework is ".Net Framework 4.0".  There wasn't an option for 4.0.3.  I checked and realised that the update for 4.0.3 (KB2600211) wasn't installed on this machine, so I installed it and rebooted, as requested.

There still isn't a 4.0.3 option in VS and I'm still getting the message.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**

VS 2010 SP1 is already installed.

Comment: You have  install Visual Studio 2010 SP1 before installing .NET Framework version 4.0.3 then it will be visible in the target framework.

Comment: Be sure you read the instructions for the extension, this part `Deploying with Silverlight`, is VERY important.  Visual Studio SP1 install the .NET Framework 4.0.3 ( its required ) I am not exactly sure how you were able to install 4.0.3 without updating Visual Studio.

Comment: I already had SP1.  Maybe I missed 2600211 in the (long) list.  If so, it let me reinstall over the top without issue.  I already have the current version of the PCL tools as well.

Comment: I had missed the Design time part of 4.0.3 (2600214) - that is now installed but hasn't made any difference.

Comment: Workaround: if I create the PCL as .Net 4 and Silverlight 5 and Add a Reference to it from the other project and then edit the PCL project Properties and set it to .Net 4 Platform Update 3, it works.  I've built a simple test solution which uses a class from the PCL in a WCF service and returns it to the Silverlight project and it works as it should.

Comment: @Ramhound VS SP1 does not install .NET Framework 4.0.3, it installs KB2468871. 4.0.3 includes KB2468871, but it it is not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To target .NET Framework 4.0.3, you need to install KB2600214, and then change the Project Properties -> Application -> Target Framework to .NET Framework 4.0.3.

Comment: It's working, now, thanks.  I think it just needed another restart.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to consult [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668079%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on Microsoft's site.  It offers a few workarounds for these Targeted Framework errors.  Personally, I ended up manually modifying this line in my csproj file:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0.3</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```